# SwiftyJson can not be imported in Swift 3.1 module compiled in 3.0.2 with Carthage

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swifty-json, carthage

I am not longer able to run my project in Xcode 8.3 as SwiftyJson will not compile in Swift 3.1.

I have updated carthage with the no use binaries flag, its checking out at 3.1.4 (their latest version), i've removed the framework and deleted its remaining files as weel as deleting all the Derived data before each run, as well as cleaned the project.

I still have Xcode 8.2.1 installed however my testing device has updated to 10.3.1 so I am no longer able to use it with that version of Xcode.

Also Apple have stopped signing iOS 10.3 and 10.2.1 so I am also no longer able to downgrade.

As simulators will do for the time being I would much rather debug and test on a physical device, thanks.

Comment: Is this a question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SwiftyJSON is not compatible with Swift3.1 yet. You might want to look at the issue raised on their github page - https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/830